# I need to go from first screen to second screen

Tags: android, flutter

I need to move from one screen to another. I made the transition from one class to another, but the main information of the second screen is indicated in the void main. How can I make the transition from one window to another without errors? So i need to transition from void main to void second. I'm sorry that my post has a lot of code, but help me please. Thanks in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

enum GenderList {male, female}
class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => Registr();
}

class Registr extends State {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  GenderList _gender;
  bool _agreement = false;



  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0), child: new Form(key: _formKey, child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
      new Text('Имя пользователя:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
      new TextFormField(validator: (value){
        if (value.isEmpty) return 'Пожалуйста введите свое имя';
      }),

      new SizedBox(height: 20.0),

      new Text('Контактный E-mail:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
      new TextFormField(validator: (value){
        if (value.isEmpty) return 'Пожалуйста введите свой Email';

        String p = "[a-zA-Z0-9+.\_\%-+]{1,256}@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,64}(.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,25})+";
        RegExp regExp = new RegExp(p);

        if (regExp.hasMatch(value)) return null;

        return 'Это не E-mail';
      }),

      new SizedBox(height: 20.0),

      new Text('Ваш пол:', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),

      Row(children: [Expanded(child:RadioListTile(
        title: const Text('Мужской'),
        value: GenderList.male,
        groupValue: _gender,
        onChanged: (GenderList value) {setState(() { _gender = value;});},
      ),
      ),
        Expanded(child: RadioListTile(title: const Text('Женский'),
            value: GenderList.female,
            groupValue: _gender,
            onChanged: (GenderList value ){setState(() {_gender=value;

            });}))
      ],
      ),
      Column(children: <Widget>[(SizedBox(height: 95.0)),
        Align(alignment:Alignment.bottomCenter ,
          child: CheckboxListTile(
            value: _agreement,
            title: new Text('Я ознакомлен'+(_gender==null?'(а)':_gender==GenderList.male?'':'а')+' с документом "Согласие на обработку персональных данных" и даю согласие на обработку моих персональных данных в соответствии с требованиями "Федерального закона О персональных данных № 152-ФЗ".'),
            onChanged: (bool value) => setState(() => _agreement = value),

          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
        RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
          if(_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
            Color color = Colors.red;
            String text;

            if (_gender == null) text = 'Выберите свой пол';
            else if (_agreement == false) text = 'Необходимо принять условия соглашения';
            else {text = 'Форма успешно заполнена'; color = Colors.green;}

            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(text), backgroundColor: color,));
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()));
          }
        }, child: Text('Проверить'), color: Colors.blue, textColor: Colors.white,),],)

    ],)));
  }
}


class NewsBoxFavourit extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyFormState();
}
class MyFormState extends State {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  }
}

class NewsBox extends StatelessWidget {

  String _imageurl;


  NewsBox( {String imageurl,}) {
    _imageurl = imageurl;
  }




    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      if (_imageurl != null && _imageurl != '') return new Container(
          color: Colors.black12,
          height: 138.0,
          child:  Row(children: [
            Image.network(_imageurl, width: 200.0, height: 150.0, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
            Expanded(child:  Container(padding:  EdgeInsets.all(5.0), child:  Column(children: [
              Text('Дата'),
              TextFormField(),
              Text('Бег'),
              TextFormField()

            ]
            ))
            ),


          ])
      );


  }
}
class NewsBoxFavourit2 extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyFormState2();
}
class MyFormState2 extends State {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  }
}
class NewsBox2 extends StatelessWidget {

  String _imageurl2;


  NewsBox2( {String imageurl2,}) {
    _imageurl2 = imageurl2;
  }




@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter,);
  if (_imageurl2 != null && _imageurl2 != '') return new Container(
      color: Colors.black12,
      height: 200.0,
      child:  Row(children: [
        Image.network(_imageurl2, width: 200.0, height: 150.0, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
        Expanded(child:  Container(padding:  EdgeInsets.all(5.0), child:  Column(children: [
          Text('Дата'),
          TextFormField(),
          Text('Отжимания'),
          TextFormField()

        ]
        ))
        ),


      ])
  );


}
}
class NewsBoxFavourit3 extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyFormState3();
}
class MyFormState3 extends State {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  }
}
class NewsBox3 extends StatelessWidget {

  String _imageurl3;


  NewsBox3( {String imageurl3,}) {
    _imageurl3 = imageurl3;
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_imageurl3 != null && _imageurl3 != '') return new Container(
        color: Colors.black12,
        height: 200.0,
        child:  Row(children: [
          Image.network(_imageurl3, width: 200.0, height: 150.0, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
          Expanded(child:  Container(padding:  EdgeInsets.all(5.0), child:  Column(children: [
            Text('Дата'),
            TextFormField(),
            Text('Пресс'),
            TextFormField()

          ]
          ))
          ),


        ])
    );


  }
}
class NewsBoxFavourit4 extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyFormState4();
}
class MyFormState4 extends State {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  }
}
class NewsBox4 extends StatelessWidget {

  String _imageurl4;


  NewsBox4( {String imageurl4,}) {
    _imageurl4 = imageurl4;
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_imageurl4 != null && _imageurl4 != '') return new Container(
        color: Colors.black12,
        height: 138.0,
        child:  Row(children: [
          Image.network(_imageurl4, width: 200.0, height: 150.0, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
          Expanded(child:  Container(padding:  EdgeInsets.all(5.0), child:  Column(children: [
            Text('Дата'),
            TextFormField(),
            Text('Приседания'),
            TextFormField()

          ]
          ))
          ),


        ])
    );


  }
}
class MyFormState5 extends State {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  }
}
class NewsBox5 extends StatelessWidget {

  String _imageurl5;


  NewsBox5( {String imageurl5,}) {
    _imageurl5 = imageurl5;
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Alignment.bottomCenter;
    if (_imageurl5 != null && _imageurl5 != '') return new Container(
        color: Colors.black12,
        height: 138.0,
        child:  Row(children: [
          Image.network(_imageurl5, width: 200.0, height: 150.0, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
          Expanded(child:  Container(padding:  EdgeInsets.all(30.0), child:  Column(children: [
            Text('Дата'),
            TextFormField(),
            Text('Прыжки'),
            TextFormField()

          ]
          ))
          ),


        ])
    );


  }
}
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {return SizedBox(width: 100 , height: 80,
      child:
      RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()));
      }, child: Text('Сформировать результаты')))
    ;
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {return SizedBox(width: 200 , height: 100,
      child:
      Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Результаты')),
      body: Center(child: RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
         Navigator.pop(context);
      }, child: Text('Назад'))),
    ));
  }
}
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
home: Scaffold(appBar: PreferredSize(preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(30.0),
  child: AppBar(centerTitle:true, title: Text('Форма ввода'),),),
body: MyForm(),),),);

 void second() =>  runApp(
 MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

home: Scaffold(
appBar:  AppBar(),

body:
ListView(children: [

  NewsBox(
    imageurl: 'https://img.rl0.ru/0e5dfa5a89802f6ae40eea1312ee89c0/c615x400i/https/news.rambler.ru/img/2019/01/25160023.223341.8124.jpeg'),
  NewsBox2(imageurl2: 'https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/1873797/pub_5e3d7968f58c3b19c8d9605e_5e40115dc0c2cd2f40ec8403/scale_1200'),
  NewsBox3(imageurl3: 'https://www.bodybuilding.com/images/2018/april/the-best-ab-workout-for-a-six-pack-header.jpg'),
  NewsBox4(imageurl4: 'http://vlzsport.ru/wp-content/uploads/prisedanie.png'),
  NewsBox4(imageurl4: 'http://vlzsport.ru/wp-content/uploads/prisedanie.png'),
  MainScreen()
],) ,
  drawer: Drawer(child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[SizedBox(height: 0,),
      Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,),

      DrawerHeader(child: new Text("Меню"),
    decoration: BoxDecoration (
        color: Colors.blueAccent), ),
      SizedBox(height: 10,),
      Align(alignment: Alignment.topLeft,),
      ListTile(
        title: Text("Программа"),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: Text("Настройки"),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
      ),
      ListTile(title: Text('Результаты'),
      trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,),
      ),

    ],
  ),),
)
)

);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have runApp() only once , to return a widget that will be the entry point for your app. After that you can go from one screen to another using Navigator.push() .
Please refer to this link that explains everything in detail :

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Answer (score 1):

I didn't actually went through your code because it is too bloated with irrelevant content. However, to pass data between one screen to another and vice-versa you just need to:

```
final bar = await Navigator.pushNamed(MyScreen2, arguments: foo);
```

Now on the `MyScreen2` you can get your data on `didChangeDependencies` for example as such:

```
final data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

If you want to pass back data from `MyScreen2` to the previous one when the route is popped, just do `Navigator.pop(context, data);` and that `data` will be assigned to the `bar` property above.